# How can I tell if "abort()" has been called on an XMLHTTPRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax

Simple question, but not obvious from the Mozilla JS docs. Anyone know the answer off the top of their head?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the standard implementation. Based on below, the only way is to check the readyState of the object, however this won't work in all browsers.

> **Syntax**
>
> XMLHttpRequest.abort() Return Value
>
> No return value.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> abort was introduced in Windows
>   Internet Explorer 7.
>
> The abort method interrupts an
>   asynchronous operation in progress.
>   (Pass true to the varAsync parameter
>   of open to create an asynchronous
>   request.)
>
> Calling abort resets the object; the
>   onreadystatechange event handler is
>   removed, and readyState is changed to
>   0 (uninitialized).

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535920(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: Warning: readyState is also changed to 0 if you loose network connection.

Answer (score 1):

W3C Spec, "The XMLHttpRequest Object":

http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/

Shortcut to the abort() method:

http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#abort

Under the heading ["Exceptions for the XMLHttpRequest Object"](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#readystatechange) it says this:

> The ABORT_ERR exception is raised when
>   the user aborts a request in
>   synchronous requests.