# Check if ajax was aborted

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am not using jquery (cause I cant in this specific project) so how do I know the request was aborted by user using .abort() method? I read a lot and there is no abort method in the object XMLHttpRequest.

I know I can chek the status and readyStatus of onreadystatechange but it does not tell me anything if the connection was aborted
thans.

Comment: but I cant listen to onreadystatechange  and trigger an event if readystatus is 0 cause when the user starts the connection it's 0 too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell if "abort()" has been called on an XMLHTTPRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064196/how-can-i-tell-if-abort-has-been-called-on-an-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: but there they did not find an answer. How does jquery do that?

Comment: @amandanovaes As long as the request has been opened, a `readyState` of `0` should look out of place and suggest an `.abort()` as even `.open()` changes it to `1`.

Comment: I am doing objeto.onreadystatechange = function() { console.log(objeto.readyState);} but it never changes to 0 when I abort. It changes to 4!

Comment: jQuery works by tracking their own special state. They start it out at `0`, and modify it as the request goes along. They evaluate the result of the request for a general "success" or "error" case. If not successful, and their state is still `0`, it's considered aborted. They raise the `error/fail` event with the status. This is a very oversimplified explanation; if you want to investigate how they do it exactly, [go read the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js).

Answer (score 2):

You can determine if the request has been aborted by testing the `readyState`, which will again be `0`.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
console.log(xhr.readyState); // 0

xhr.open('GET', '/');
console.log(xhr.readyState); // 1

xhr.abort();
console.log(xhr.readyState); // 0
```

If you need to know *when* it's aborted, not just *if*, then you'll have to [use `onabort`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#handler-xhr-onabort) as [`onreadystatechange` won't be triggered by it](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-abort%28%29-method).

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onabort = function () {
    console.log('Was aborted', xhr.readyState);
};

xhr.open('GET', '/');
xhr.send();

xhr.abort(); // Was aborted 0
```

Comment: please take a look at my code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22565513/ajax-readystate-never-returns-0-on-abort . Besides when I use onabort it says roperty 'onabort' of object #<XMLHttpRequest> is not a function